# Facebook feed group with images

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps

I have script for feed message on facebook group. It works, but I need send feed with images. But don't know how to do it. For feed message I use `$facebook->api('<group_id>/feed', 'POST', $attr);` and in $attr is access_token and message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
$postData = array(
    'access_token' => '{your access token}', 
    'message' => '{message}',
    'picture' => '{image url}'
   );
```

Then

```
$facebook->api('<group_id>/feed', 'POST', $postData);
```

In addition you need to double check that the feed URL posting is enabled on your app settings.